# How to resolve IllegalStateException and ParserConfigurationException for finding location in android studio by using apache OpenNLP

Tags: android, opennlp, bin

```
 package com.example.dell.apacheopennlp;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME;
    import opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel;
    import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerME;
    import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerModel;
    import opennlp.tools.util.Span;
    public class apacheOpenNLP extends AppCompatActivity {
         TokenNameFinderModel locationModel = null;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
            setContentView (R.layout.activity_apache_open_nlp);
            final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtView);
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
             StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            TokenizerModel tokenModel = null;
            try {
                inputStream = getAssets ( ).open ("en-token.bin");
                tokenModel = new TokenizerModel (inputStream);
                inputStream.close ( );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ( );
                txt.setText (e.toString ( ) + " inside catch of token");
            }

            if (tokenModel != null) {
                TokenizerME tokenizer = new TokenizerME (tokenModel);
                String paragraph = "Tutorialspoint is located in Hyderabad";
                String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize (paragraph);
                InputStream locationInputStream = null;

                try {
                    locationInputStream = getAssets ( ).open ("en-ner-location.bin");
                    locationModel = new TokenNameFinderModel (locationInputStream);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ( );
                    txt.setText (e.toString ( ) + " inside catch of location");
                }
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try  {
                            NameFinderME nameFinder = null;
                            if (locationModel != null) {
                                txt.setText ("Location model is not empty");
                                nameFinder = new NameFinderME (locationModel);

                                //after this line..its goes in the catch and the app crashes 
                                Span nameSpans[] = nameFinder.find (tokens);
                                String result = null;
                                for (Span s : nameSpans)
                                   result += s.toString ( );
                                txt.setText (result);
                                // txt.setText ("Location model is not empty");*/
                            }
                            else{
                                txt.setText ("Location model is empty");
                            }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        txt.setText(e.toString ()+"++++++");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start();

        }

        }

    }
```

I am using the apache openNLP to find the location in a sentence and i am getting errors when it passes at nameFinder = new NameFinderME(locationModel);
I have tried other examples when it uses NameFinderME, it did not work also. Can somebody figure out the issue?

```
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing
                  at opennlp.tools.util.XmlUtil.createDocumentBuilder(XmlUtil.java:42)
                  at opennlp.tools.util.featuregen.GeneratorFactory.createDOM(GeneratorFactory.java:557)
                  at opennlp.tools.util.featuregen.GeneratorFactory.create(GeneratorFactory.java:590)
                  at opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderFactory.createFeatureGenerators(TokenNameFinderFactory.java:189)
                  at opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderFactory.createContextGenerator(TokenNameFinderFactory.java:150)
                  at opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME.<init>(NameFinderME.java:83)
                  at com.example.dell.apacheopennlp.apacheOpenNLP$1.run(apacheOpenNLP.java:60)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

W/System.err: Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing
                  at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setFeature(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:101)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenNLP: documentBuilderFactory.setFeature("http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing", true) ParserConfigurationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243013/opennlp-documentbuilderfactory-setfeaturehttp-javax-xml-xmlconstants-featur)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using a more recent version of Apache OpenNLP you can directly pass the URL which is returned by getResource to the TokenizerModel constructor.

```
TokenizerModel tokenModel = 
    new TokenizerModel(apacheOpenNLP.class.getResource("en-token.bin"));
```

You should not load the model each time you invoke the tokenizer, the model should be reused for multiple invocations.

Comment: I have done the changes but i am still getting the same error: java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Joern ..can you please help me.. I have been able to locate the bin files by placing both en-token.bin and en-ner-location.bin in the asset folder..Then I get the bin file by using getAssets ( ).open ("en-ner-location.bin"); but when it comes at nameFinder = new NameFinderME (model); I got the error of: java.lang.IllegalStateException:java.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException ..

Comment: We never tested OpenNLP on Android, please provide the exception with stack trace and also tell which Android version you are trying to run it on.

Comment: I'm using Android studio with version is 3.1.4.  I have updated the code at the top. Please help its urgent

Comment: Is there any other way to get location from a sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the nameFinder to be declared as **TokenNameFinder** interface type?

Just try to replace

```
NameFinderME nameFinder = null
```

with

```
TokenNameFinder nameFinder = null
```

Rest all should be same.

Comment: I have made the changes but unfortunately I am getting the same error. IW/System.err: Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setFeature